# How could I change the font and background color in the action bar sherlock?

Tags: android, fonts, colors, actionbarsherlock

I want to be able to change the action bars font and the background color. How could I go about doing this? I've searched everywhere for this and none of the options seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the very Sherlock website about [Theming](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html)?

> Theming of the action bar to work on all devices is a very
>   straightforward and simple process. You should follow the [existing](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html)
>   theming recommendations for customizing the native action bar with
>   some minor tweaks.

And to help you with the problem, you can also use the web tool called [actionbarstylegenerator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/).

> The Android Action Bar Style Generator allows you to easily create a
>   simple, attractive and seamless custom action bar style for your
>   Android application. It will generate all necessary nine patch assets
>   plus associated XML drawables and styles which you can copy straight
>   into your project.